# HOWTO: Authenticate the client application in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, security

Scenario:

I have a WCF service hosted on a server in an intranet. It exposes a single method.

I have 100,000+ Windows clients on the same intranet.

Running on each client is an application which calls the single method on the WCF service.

However, I only want calls from that application to be able to make that call. Any other client applications running on the client under the same user account should not be able to call the method.

Question:

How can we achieve this type of security? Is a shared secret (which might anyway be discoverable via reverse-compilation) the only method?

Comment: You could use a client certificate or the DNS name if you don't want the key to be present in your app. Whether those methods are feasible depends on how the system administration is set up by your domain admins.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx
This sample uses username/password authentication that you can easily configure in your client app settings and pass them through with the call. Or you can you use token authentication that expires after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Application identity is usually based on some client secret. But if the attacker application is running with the same credentials as the authorized application, then it is really hard to prevent the attacker application from calling your service. How can you prevent the attacker application from getting the secret?

If you can have the authorized application run under any account, you could look into [grouped managed service accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128431.aspx). In this case, the accounts (and passwords) are managed by Windows. You could then use certificate authentication and only give the managed account read privileges to the private key.

Grouped managed service accounts do require that your domain controller runs on Windows 2012 R2 though.